# Synonym for "not the kind of" or "not the type of"

Tags: synonyms, abbreviations

Is there a synonym or more succinct way to say "not the kind of" or "not the type of" as in:

"This wrench is not the kind of wrench that can be used to open this machine."

or

"This vitamin is not the type of vitamin that provides high levels of vitamin C."

Comment: Yes, what you said works for the wrench case, and the second case can be shortened to "This vitamin does not contain high levels of vitamin C", but it doesn't quite capture the spirit of "not the kind of".  Implied in "not the kind of" is that we are talking about a category of things for which some specific sub-category doesn't match a sub-category of interest.

Comment: *not the right **wrench/vitamin** or **one***

Comment: This wrench is unsuitable for opening this machine.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK sounds like an answer.

Comment: The two examples can be addressed with *won't*: "This type of wrench won't open this machine." and "This type of vitamin won't provide high levels of Vitamin C." I'd certainly not suggest it's a general answer though, to what I think is a good question. Can I suggest another example: "This style of architecture is not the kind that you'd expect to see here."

Comment: More clumsy than many of those suggested above, but you can also elide the phrase *of [noun]* - "This wrench is not the kind that can ..." and "This vitamin is not the kind that provides ...".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @chasleyfromUK's *unsuitable*, you might consider

> - inapt
> - inadequate
> - inappropriate
> - incapable
> - ineffective
> - unfit
> - unfitted

Comment: ...  and 'unexpected', 'unsuccessful', 'uncontrollable', 'indescribable' and any number of negative adjectives, depending on circumstance. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I think the Question is asking for an *exclusive* collective term which can be used without rewriting the rest of the sentence.  Something that explictly means 'the subset that does not fulfil these criteria' (not that I think there *is* such a term, by the way).

Comment: @JHCL - you've put it very well, "the subset that does not fulfil these criteria" is what I'm trying to capture

Comment: @JHCL The rewrite would be minimal: *This wrench in inapt for opening this machine* or *This vitamin is incapable of providing high levels of vitamin C.* If OP is looking to repeat *wrench* he might say *This wrench is an **inapposite** (or **inappropriate** or **unsuitable**) wrench to open this machine.* Or maybe just *the wrong wrench* . . .

Comment: @bib - I don't disagree with what you're saying, but it doesn't represent a generic solution in my opinion.